# Find the missing link

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

Here are some words that share a link to a single word, used in different ways...

- Street (where runners go)
- Respect (a gesture)
- Ribbon (a flourish)
- Reflex (a weapon)
- Play (might be awe-inspiring or just awful)
- Front (a place with a view)

**What's the word that links to all these?**

---

You smart people won't need any more hints* but I can add words to the list, if you really need it.

* (OK, maybe two then)

---

And with thanks to @xnor and @randal'thor for discussion on format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer I came up with is

> **Bow, and its homonyms.**

- Street:

  > Actually, this is the only one I am not sure about, but research suggests Bow Street Runners, the earliest police force in London.
- Respect:

  > To bow, leaning forward in a gesture of respect.
- Ribbon:

  > A bow, as found decorating presents or hair.
- Reflex:

  > Bow, as in shooting arrows. Reflex is a type of bow shape.
- Play:

  > Bow, used in playing stringed musical instruments. (I can attest, it can sound beautiful or down-right awful).
- Front:

  > Bow, a part of a boat/ship.

Comment: If anyone knows how to put lists/bullet points into a spoiler block, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Correct, and full marks for the explanations!

Comment: Sharp as bow-arrow +1

Comment: @Joffan Glad I got it right. Was my explanation of Bow Street (Runners) the correct one, as well? I am not native to that side of the pond, which makes it difficult to be sure.

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 Yes, that was the street and the reference I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

All are related with

> sports/competitions:

Respect

> Respect won.

Ribbon

> Ribbon cut to start

Runner

> Many racing competitions

Reflex

> Reflex oh yes this is must

Play

> Definitely people play

Comment: Nice try! but not the link I was looking for...